# Configuring WSUS server to use NIC#1 (LAN#1) to push, NIC#2 (LAN#2) to sync

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, wsus, static-routes

Oh boy... This should be easy, but my head is swimming. I work in two domain environments. My primary domain (LAN1) is completely offline, but has regular domain services (DC, DHCP, router (legacy, used for DMZ)...). My lab domain (LAN2) is online, and also has regular domain services.

LAN1 (production)

add: 10.0.1.0/24

LAN2 (lab):

add: 10.10.10.0/24

router: 10.10.10.1

I'm working on deploying a WSUS server to service the devices LAN1. The server is a Hyper-V VM configured with Server 2012 Core with RRAS and WSUS, and two virtual adapters (one connected to each LAN). It is hosted in Hyper-V Server 2012. The host server has four NICs (2 teams) for LAN1, one NIC reserved for host, and one NIC connected to LAN2. Both LAN1 teams and the LAN2 NIC are connected to external virtual switches for use in Hyper-V.

My goal is to have the WSUS server joined to LAN1's domain, to manage updates to the devices in the 10.0.1.0/24 subnet, and to use LAN2's connection to sync and download updates.

What is the best way to accomplish this without encountering DNS issues or crosstalk? Would a static routes work if configured correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b5f41b0e-6072-46c1-b61b-3c7b77c55f1f/server-with-two-network-adapters-one-on-wan-side-and-a-second-on-lan-side) will have all the information you need to get this working.

In a nutshell, your LAN2 NIC must be assigned a default gateway (10.10.10.1) and a DNS server IP address capable of resolving internet DNS names.  The LAN1 NIC **must not** be assigned a gateway and the internal DNS server IP address.

You need to change the binding order by going to Network & Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings > Advanced (hold down alt if you don't see it) > Advanced Settings and to make LAN1 is first on the list so it tries this firs for network services.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris. I implemented this solution and it's working great. The only additional configuration I had to do was to add a "mydomain.com" forward lookup zone on my lab DNS server and create host records to point to my production DC's. But yea, WSUS is currently doing a post-installation sync, and everything looks good.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help! :)